# Cloud Firestore write ops do not work unless thread is blocked

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using Cloud Firebase Java admin API to write data into my Firestore instance.

All the methods writing some data into the Firestore return an instance of `ApiFuture`. Now, the problem is that unless I call `get()` method on the returned instance, the data does not make it to the Firestore.

This problem exists for both singular and batch write operations.

I've tried both completely ignoring the future and adding a callback via `addListener(Runnable, Executor)`. The callback is executed, but the data is not written either way.

And if I try to execute `get()` in another thread (from the one where the write operation was invoked), an `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException` is thrown: `CANCELLED: io.grpc.Context was cancelled without error`.

One more interesting detail is that if I block the thread with `Thread.sleep()` for a sufficient time (~3 seconds in my case), the data is written properly.

Does anybody know what may cause this issue?

I'm using Firebase admin API of version 5.7.0.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the actual code that you're trying in each case?  That will be a lot more clear.

Comment: Chances are your JVM process is exiting before the data is written to the backend. Is this the case in your code?

Comment: Dear OP, if you have managed to resolve this issue then please update